# An object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property in C#

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting an error on `RunUiThread` line

> An object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property

```
public override void OnUpdate (Detector.Detections detections, Java.Lang.Object item)
{
  // I am getting an error in the following       
  RunOnUiThread(() => DisplayText());

}

public void DisplayText ()
{
   Toast.MakeText(this, "Something", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: why does DisplayText need to be a static method?

Comment: No it does not has to be. no matter either static or not, same issue exist.

Comment: Did you try: `RunOnUiThread(() => this.DisplayText());` ?

Comment: Have just tried and same error. Please see screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because you are probably using `RunOnUiThread()` inside a static method.

If you do use it in a static method, you need a reference to the current `Activity`, but that doesn't always make sense. Try to avoid static methods for these scenario's. However, if you really need to, you could pass the Activity to the static method as a parameter.

Comment: I am not using `Xamarin Forms`, I am in `Xamarin.Android`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the Xamarin.Android way to get to the Activity/Context.

Comment: I have got the following error `Unhandled Exception:System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: Hm I've just tried it, and the Context is indeed an `Application` type instead of `Activity` which I expected. You would be better of to pass the Activity instance as a parameter to a static method that requires the `RunOnUiThread()` method.